# Need help improving eye pair detection

Tags: opencv

My fundamental problem is I have an iOS (iPhone) application which uses the front-facing camera (480x640) and need to detect face liveness.

I'm currently trying to accomplish this using eye blink detection. I do not want to rely on iOS CIDetector functionality. So I've decided to examine this approach:
http://www.technolabsz.com/2013/05/eye-blink-detection-using-opencv-in.html

This approach relies on eye pair detection using the Haar classifiers (mcs_eyepair_big or mcs_eyepair_small). The first challenge I'm running to is that the eye pair detection is unreliable. It doesn't work consistently, even though frontalface_alt works quite well. I've tried with good lighting both far and close from the camera, and can't get consistent detection even close to the camera. And it won't work PERIOD with glasses.

This is my detection code:

```
small_eye_pair_cascade.detectMultiScale(mat, objects, 1.1, 0,
  CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
  cv::Size(15, 75));
```

If it does not detect using small eyepair, then I fall back to large eyepair with the same detectMultiScale arguments as for the small eyepair. I am doing detection on the entire camera image.

Does anyone have suggestions to improve success? Example questions:
1) Should I use different detectMultiScale arguments?
2) Does cropping the image to the upper half of the face boundaries improve detection, or does it just improve performance?
3) Should I choose an entirely different approach not using the eyepair classifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the area around the eyes using facial landmarks detectors, such as flandmark detector:
http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/

or STASM:
http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/

They are more reliable than haar cascades.

Comment: Thanks. How would you suggest applying those two implementations to detect liveness?

Comment: I just found this other post you made which answers my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386285/blink-detection-with-asm-co-ordinates

Comment: Thanks. STASM works quite well. I compiled is as a static library for iOS.

Comment: Although Stasm does work well, it is too computationally expensive for real-time mobile processing. I ended up getting the Haar single eye classifier to work well after tweaking with the settings and setting ROI to the likely locations of the eyes.

Comment: @jacob how did you tweak? I need help.